# type check a python list, array or series for only numeric types

Tags: python-3.x, types

I'm just getting up to speed on type checking and wanting to give it a go.

IIUC, if I want to average a list and return a float, I could do:

```
def average(x_lst: list) -> float:
    return sum(x_lst)/float(len(x_lst))
```

But if I want to also allow arrays and series, then I can do:

```
from typing import TypeVar
lst_like = TypeVar(list, np.array, pd.Series)

def average(x_lst: lst_like) -> float:
    return sum(x_lst)/float(len(x_lst))
```

but what if I want to check for lst_like where items are only numeric?

can that be done at the type check level or would I still handle as a unit test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a generic sequence type and specify its contents:

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence

def average(numbers: Sequence[float]) -> float:
    return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
```